# Why is my function not firing onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to call a JavaScript function on a HTML website by clicking a button(I have included this code on the website using Firebug), when I run the following code on Notepad++ or any other editor, it works, but when I copy this code to a website and click the button, it gives me:

> error:: change_value() is not defined

My code is like this:

**JavaScript**: (I have copied this on header section of the webpage)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_value() {
    alert("Test");
} 
</script>
```

**HTML**: (I have copied this on body section)

```
<button onclick="change_value()">Click Here !</button >
```

I have tried with all code written only in the body section same error.

Comment: This: _"i have included this code on the website using firebug"_ seems crucial to your question - what exactly are you trying to do here?  Can you expand on this part of it?

Comment: Just execute the function in the console instead of manually adding it into the source.

Comment: I think you should reword your title.

Comment: Not working for me as well.  

https://jsfiddle.net/tLq5n8hd/1/

Comment: @Sid — The code in that JS Fiddle is not the same as the code in the question because the load type preference is set to wrap the code in an onload handler function (which changes the scope of everything)

Comment: I got it to work by adding event listener.

https://jsfiddle.net/tLq5n8hd/2/

Comment: @sid Your original one will work if you [change the option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Fai.png) that Quentin alluded to.

Comment: @Sid — Adding the event listener with JavaScript instead of HTML solves the problem **you introduced** by using JS Fiddle and wrapping the code with an onload handler.

Comment: @Quentin, that makes sense.  I agree.

Comment: @Quentin you are right it works on JS Fiddle but not on the HTML page. My target was to change the value of an actual document e.g., document.forms[0].elements[0].value='Volvo'. with firebug console i can get it work but it doesn't change the html value, my question is how can i change the value of HTML using javascript.

Comment: @starsAround — As James said, the original code works. The problem has to be something to do with how you are including it on the page. Your question doesn't include enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin - Actually i don't know how to achieve that as James said since i have poor javascript knowledge. I have used javascript on html header section and html tags on body section - so i am getting error (function not defined). is there any way could you please help me to write that code and where to put that code in to run without getting error.   general question , can i change the value on html file through javascript (e.g. on the webpage it run with car="Honda" but i want to change it to car="Volvo"). Thanks

Comment: @starsAround — You need a [MCVE] that demonstrates the **problem**, not code which as far as we can tell **works**.

Answer (score 1):

Adding your JS script in the source code of the page already displayed (using firebug or any debugger in fact) won't do anything, as this tag (`<script>`) is computed by the browser when it is loading the page.

Instead, use the developper tools (console) to define your function ; it should now work properly.

Edit :

Tested in Chrome. After manually adding a button at the top of a Stack Overflow page :

```
<button onclick="toast()">HELLO</button>
```

I tested two things :

Adding a `script` tag directly into the source code :

```
<script>function toast(){alert("Hello");}</script>
```

Clicking on the button did not work.

Now, using the developper console and defining the same function, clicking on the button properly displayed an alert.

Edit 2 : To precise what I mean by using the developper console : normally in Firebug, you should see a "Console" panel. If you want to define a js function "on the run" (when your page is already loaded), just type its definition within the console ; in this case :

```
function toast(){alert("Hello");}
```

It works quite the same on all browsers.

As Ahmad Bamieh suggests in the comments, you can also add a `<script>` tag from an external JS script, example :

```
function addScript( src,callback) { 
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
    s.onload=callback; 
    document.body.appendChild( s );
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect.. functions are evaluated only after the click is triggered. actually the browser runs eval() on the string value of onclick property. if it was defined after or before the element doesnt matter. its executed and evaluated when its triggered.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh I think you misunderstood ; I completly agree with what you said, but I meant that the `<script>` tag is only evaluated when loading the page, meaning that the brand new function defined within this tag doesn't exist.

Comment: ah yes, this is correct as its parsed as text, unless you add it from javascript as external script

`function addScript( src,callback) {
  var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  s.onload=callback;
  document.body.appendChild( s );
}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my purpose of this code is to change the value on a webpage not on GUI but on the actual html code. I need a function to call on click event to change that value. I am a beginner on JavaScript and I am a bit confused about function scope. Why the same code works on a editor but not adding on the webpage

Comment: My question is  1.Why the same code works on a notepad++ but not on the webpage, as @Quentin mentioned there are some scope issues how can i resolved that, is there anything can i do to call that function ?   2. if i had to use console on firebug (which i did try before but couldn't do it)? All i need to achieve this on click event documents[0].elements[0].value='Audi', how can i do that?

Comment: @starsAround — The scope issues existed only in sid's demo. Not in your code or the code in this answer.

Comment: @Ephi — You're a bit confused about who wrote the question.

Comment: @starsAround I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do, especially how you're trying to do it. What do you mean when you run it from notepad ? By "actual html code", you mean what is really written in the html file ? Edit your question to add those informations, try to not forget anything :)